# Solar system simulator

Tags: math, collision-detection

I have created a solar system generator in Java.  I was wondering, if I have an asteroid in the sytem and want to check if it has coliided with a planet would I just get the distance between the asteroid and each planet and if the distance minus the radius was 0 or less it would be a collision. Is that the correct math?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it? That might be a good thing to do instead of just asking.

Comment: This probably isn't a question for stack overflow. To answer your question though, lets say the distance between the centers is D. You don't need D=0 for collision. They'd collide even if D<(R+r) where R and r are the radii of the planet and asteroid respectively.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your distance is relative to the center point of your two entities, then you are almost correct. You'll want to subtract the radius of both the planet and the asteroid from the distance calculation. They are exactly touching if the result of your subtraction is zero, and have collided when the result is less than zero.

Comment: Then you can get into the messier things like athmosphere (significant e.g. with Jupiter or other low-density bodies).

Comment: You should consider *gravity* long before you worry about anything so fantastically rare as atmosphere-grazing.